# How to debug an X session shutting down by itself

Tags: linux, crash, xorg, session, session-manager

I currently have a very curious "crash" under X when I run a particular application. I say "crash" because as far as I can tell neither the application (HandBrake's ghb) or X crash. I've verified both by running under gdb and they both seem to exit of their own accord.

Looking at my system log there is no sign of crash, just of my X session shutting down:

```
Jan 22 12:16:03 danny dbus[340]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus org.freedesktop.hostname1.service'
Jan 22 12:16:03 danny systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
Jan 22 12:16:04 danny dbus[340]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Jan 22 12:16:04 danny systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
Jan 22 12:16:05 danny lightdm[27656]: pam_unix(lightdm:session): session closed for user alex
```

And my .xsession-errors just shows the consequence of X going away:

```
[../../i3-4.13/i3bar/src/xcb.c:1074] ERROR: X11 connection was closed unexpectedly - maybe your X server terminated / crashed?
[27849:27849:0122/121605:ERROR:x11_util.cc(87)] X IO error received (X server probably went away)
[libi3] ../../i3-4.13/libi3/font.c Using X font -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--13-120-75-75-C-70-iso10646-1
```

Obviously something that ghb is doing is bringing something down in a critical way but it's hard to tell what. Given there are no crashes or core dumps what's the best way to debug this? Is there a way to snoop on the X messages and work out what the last command sent to the server way? Could this be a broken toolkit?